# What is water in Slime Rancher used for?

Tags: slime-rancher

One of the Vacpack upgrades unlocks a vac tank used exclusively for water. The game seems a little vague on the purpose of this, what can you use water for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Water can be used to:

- Damage and destroy the Tarr
- Temporarily stop a Rad Slime's radiation aura
- Destroy a Crystal Slime's crystal formations
- Temporarily stop a Quantum Slime's ability to align with one of its other possible realities
- Snuff out a Mosaic Slime's fire glints
- Temporarily extinguish a Fire Slime's flames
- Power Drones, by watering their flower-shaped station

Despite the game mentioning watering crops, water cannot be used to speed up the growth of plants in a garden. An upgrade, the Sprinkler, fills that role instead.